# PagedCollectionView groupings don't seem to automatically be refreshed when a new element is added to the source collection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, wpfdatagrid

I'm using a `PagedCollectionView` to bind an `ObservableCollection<T>` to a `DataGrid` in my Silverlight app. In this case, the source collection can incur an unbounded number of updates during its lifespan. It seems, however, that if I'm using a `PropertyGroupDescription` to group the elements in the `DataGrid` then I need to reapply that grouping using `PagedCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(...)` every time the source collection is updated with an element that doesn't fit into an existing grouping. Is there any way to make the groupings refresh/recalculate automatically?

```
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataItems
    {
        get         { return _dataItems;  }
        private set { _dataItems = value; }
    }

    public PagedCollectionView ItemsView
    {
        get         { return _itemsView;  }
        private set { _itemsView = value; }
    }

    public MyGridControl()
    {
        // Initialize data members
        DataItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        ItemsView = new PagedCollectionView(GridDataItems);

        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyGridControl_Loaded);
    }

    private void MyGridControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _myGrid.ItemsSource = ItemsView;
    }

    public void RegisterDataItem(DataItem item)
    {
        DataItems.Add(item);
        /* To get grouping to work like I want, I have to add this:
         * ItemsView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
         * ItemsView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("GroupName"));                     
         */            
    }

    public void UnregisterError(DataItem item)
    {
        DataItem.Remove(item);            
    }
```

Thanks, and let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as far as I can tell, the grouping operation appears to be a once-off operation that is performed on the data as it exists at the time that the `PagedCollectionView.GroupDescriptions` collection is manipulated. It seems that the desired groupings do indeed need to be re-applied when the source collection is changed.

I did find one alternative approach for my specific case. Since I'm using an ObservableCollection for the source collection of the view, I can wire up something to the `CollectionChanged` event of that source collection wherein the `PagedCollectionView.GroupDescriptions` collection gets cleared and the desired `GroupDescription` is then reapplied. This doesn't seem totally compliant with good OO practices, nor is it usable if the source collection for the view doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

I'll leave this open a little longer in case anyone can offer another approach, otherwise I'll just concede.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in Reflector, the Groupings **are** correctly processed but if you use view in a `DataGrid` with `IsReadOnly == true` you won't see the groupings reflected while changing the source collection.

Comment: I wasn't using IsReadOnly. There must be another reason.